# How to add my Ubuntu 12.10 to my windows xp boot.ini file?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-xp

I have a primary 80GB HDD which is partitioned into 3 drives (Core, Data & Extended) with Windows Xp installed in the C drive (Core - With NTFS file system). I have a secondary 500GB HDD which is partitioned by ubuntu 12.10 into 2 drives seen in Linux only (EXT4 file system).

When i installed the Ubuntu 12.10 installed properly without much issues. But when i restarted the system boots directly into the Windows XP. If i press F8 and go to my secondary drive i can boot into Ubuntu and work there without much issues. I even installed  KDE there and logged in to both Unity and KDE without any issues.

I want to know if it is possible to add my Ubuntu to my Windows XP boot.ini file even though both are into separate physical hard drives and file systems ?!! If so, can someone provide me the step by step method to do that to be able to see dual boot option without having the need to press F8 and choose the secondary drive from BIOS mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or just change the BIOS boot order to put the other drive first, and boot from its GRUB (which should contain both windows and linux selections.

Answer (score 1):

Use EasyBCD:
1-Open It!
2-"Add a new entry"
3-> "Linux/BSD" Tab
4-Type:"GRUB 23
  Name : 
  Drive: 
5-"Add Entry"
6-"BCD Deployment" (on the left)
7-Select "Install the Windows XP ..."
8-"Write MBR"
You can reboot now and enjoy!:D
I've just copied this from dualbooting btw Ubuntu and Win8 (after intalling win8)
I didn't test that but it worked for me on Win8 (not XP) :/
Try it and let me know :D